# Set ForeignKey before save in form with two models

Tags: python, django

I have searched around for this, but could not find anything which works for my situation. I have a `User` and `UserProfile` modelform in my app.

My forms.py looks like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class  UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name', 'avatar', 'birthday', 'usertype', 'daw', 'usergenre')
```

and my views.py look like this:

```
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='upf')
        if form.is_valid():
            if form2.is_valid():
                form.save()
                form2.user = form.username
                form2.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserForm(prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')            

    return render(request, 'profile/register.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

See now my issue is that when I save the UserProfile instance, it does not have the required `ForeignKey(User)` set relating to the newly saved `User` instance, how do I set this before saving? Obviously I will have to do it after the `User` instance has been saved, but how do I then get the "request.user" of the User instance we just made and set the `ForeignKey` in UserProfile to that?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from Submission.storage import OverwriteStorage

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    def is_square_png(self):
        if not self.name.endswith('.png'):
            raise ValidationError("You may only upload .png files!")
        else:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(self)
            if not h == w:
                raise ValidationError("This picture is not square! Your picture must be equally wide as its height.")
            else:
                if not (h + w) >= 1000:
                    raise ValidationError("This picture is too small! The minimum dimensions are 500 by 500 pixels.")
                else:
                    if not (h + w) < 2000:
                        raise ValidationError("This picture is too big! The maximum dimensions are 1000 by 1000 pixels.")
        return self

    def generate_user_folder_avatar(instance, filename):
        return "static/users/%s/%s.png" % (instance.user, 'avatar')

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_avatar,storage=OverwriteStorage(),validators=[is_square_png],blank=True)

    usertype_choices = [
        ('PR', 'Producer'),
        ('ME', 'Mastering Engineer'),
        ('CP', 'Composer'),
        ('SI', 'Singer'),
        ('AR', 'Artist'),
        ('DJ', 'Disk Jockey'),
        ('LI', 'Listener'),
        ('OT', 'Other'),
    ]

    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                 choices=usertype_choices,
                                 default='PR')
    daw_choices = [
        ('FL', 'FL Studio'),
        ('AB', 'Live'),
        ('BT', 'Bitwig Studio'),
        ('CS', 'SONAR X3'),
        ('CB', 'Cubase'),
        ('AP', 'Apple Logic'),
        ('RE', 'Reason'),
        ('SO', 'Sony ACID'),
        ('PR', 'Pro Tools'),
        ('ON', 'Studio One'),
        ('MT', 'Digital Performer'),
        ('SA', 'Samplitude'),
        ('MC', 'Mixcraft'),
        ('RP', 'Reaper'),
        ('AR', 'Ardour'),
        ('OT', 'Other'),
        ('NO', 'None'),
    ]

    daw = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=daw_choices,default='NO')
    usergenre = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True)

    joined = models.TimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followers",blank=True)
    status = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: edit and display your model

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Comment: your wish granted and executed

Comment: how far did my answer help

Comment: It didn't, check the comment I just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having this in your model as the Foreignkey `user`.

```
from yourapp.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

def register(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds -- which is optional.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        form = UserForm(data=request.POST, prefix='upf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, prefix='upf')

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user_reg = form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user_reg.set_password(user_reg.password)
            user_reg.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = form2.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user_reg

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'avatar' in request.FILES:
                profile.avatar = request.FILES['avatar']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful --- which is optional.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print form.errors, form2.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        form = UserForm(prefix='upf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response(
            'profile/register.html',
            {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'registered': registered},
        context)
```

Comment: user is not defined. i have seen i will edit right away

Comment: Now it's saying "This field is required" on every field when I press submit.

Comment: which field... whats the name of the field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103152/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-transformer).

Comment: Why did you think so?